# Secure TCP traffic to backend server with nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have a web-app consisting of front- and back-end services. I want to secure my front-end service with let's encrypt certificate, but then I have to use secured connection between front- and back-end. I have the back-end service served on a custom port. For securing back-end I want to use nginx to proxy my server. However, I am struggling to get it right. Here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 8082;
    server_name <my_domain_name>;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/<my_domain>/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/<my_domain>/privkey.pem;
    ssl_ciphers               HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_protocols             TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 SSLv3;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8081;
    }
}
```

<s>First, I just wanted to get it through, without ssl. But it does not work like this, nothing is served on 8082. If</s> it works, I thought I could use my letsencrypt certificates here, though I'm not sure, whether it is possible and I understand things correctly.

I would appreciate any help! Thanks a lot in advance!

**Update**

I figured out the problem was in iptables. After I added the port 8082 to them, it worked. What I don't understand, why I can connect to the port 8081, although it is not in the iptables.

However, now I get `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` when I try https://my_domain:8082.

I also tried to add `ssl` to the `listen` directive, like `listen 8082 ssl;`. Then I get `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

Comment: is there any service you are running on port 80 ??

Comment: Yes, there is, why?

Comment: in nginx you can even redirect to proxy backend from subdomains or sub directory ( means uris) & also if there is also a service running on port 80, then just change the port that you are listening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record. The problem was indeed in the directive `listen`.
Adding

```
listen 8082 ssl;
```

and removing

```
ssl on;
```

solved it.

It is a mystery, why it didn't work and gave me `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` before. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
location @backend {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

@backend is a named location which allows you to reference it like a variable i.e. like

```
location / {
    error_page 404 = @backend;
}
```

For your problem try something like

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

Comment: Yes, i tried this too. It does not change anything. I still get `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: Is the backend on localhost thus 0.0.0.0? Is that Port connectable? Did you try simplifying the proxy_pass to be just proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8081;

Comment: Yes, it is on localhost. I can do requests from outside by http://<ip>:8081, but requests to http://<ip>:8082 do not work. I tried to just write proxy_pass 0.0.0.0:8081 - with no effect.